# How to handle Multiple Loops in one page?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on E-commerce multi vendors so in home page there is about 10 queries I should run in just home page in order to get the require products for each section some of the queries:

```
$topProducts = Product::topSellingProducts()
                            ->with('discounts')
                            ->take(5)
                            ->get();

$topOffers = Product::discountedProducts()
                        ->mainImage()
                        >with('discounts')
                        ->take(20)
                        ->inRandomOrder()
                        ->get();

$genralProducts = Product::mainImage()
                        ->with('discounts')
                        ->take(20)
                        ->inRandomOrder()
                        ->get();
```

My questions:

1. How does the global website handle the home page ( like amazon, ebay, Alibaba etc ..) there is a lot of things in home page and the page is loading so fast!?
2. Is there any way to make all queries just one ?
3. What the best way I have to follow to make the home page fast with big data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `ajax` loading of different sections of your home page.. so:

- Your home page loads HTML with few `div`s, with different ID's
- at the end of the HTML, you put a logic, which then pulls, in async manner, the actual content of each of the Blocks, you want to populate. But at this point your initial HTML is done loading.
- At the very moment the `ajax` call for (example: Clothes) loads, you can set the contents of `<div id="clothes"></div>` to be populated with the returned data from the ajax call for Clothes.. Same for each different section..
- This also gives you the ability to later refresh only specific blocks with new products, without visitor reloading the page..

This is one approach.

Another approach is for you to have a really good caching mechanism, which uses geo-location, so that the content is all within the HTML, but is already cached to the geo-edge-location, and is lightning fast for visitors around that location..

And of course, there are MANY other ways for this to be accomplished..

Comment: Thank you so much! I know about the first approach but the second one is new! can you please explain more with example or resource to clear the point with thankful :)

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/ is one, you can simply search for `edge location caching` or `CDN` .. there are plenty of resources..